# log as I want unpermitted parameters request with rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, actioncontroller

I read there is `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise` action controller, but I don't want run a raise exception.

I need to run my own method. It's possible? How?

For exemple, if I want log in special SQL table the unpermitted_parameters.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

The values can be :log to write a message on the logger or :raise to raise ActionController::UnpermittedParameters exception. The default value is :log in test and development environments, false otherwise.

So it looks like that you can't without overriding the method `ActionController::Parameters#unpermitted_parameters!`

Here is the original implementation:

```
module ActionController
  class Parameters < ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    def unpermitted_parameters!(params)
      unpermitted_keys = unpermitted_keys(params)
      if unpermitted_keys.any?
        case self.class.action_on_unpermitted_parameters
        when :log
          name = "unpermitted_parameters.action_controller"
          ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(name, keys: unpermitted_keys)
        when :raise
          raise ActionController::UnpermittedParameters.new(unpermitted_keys)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

you could add another case branch and implement you logic there.